# Openpyxl changes the content_type.xml and the XLSX needs to be repaired before opening it

Tags: excel, openpyxl

If I load a workbook, make a change to it, then save it as a separate document I get an error when I try to open this new document in Excel. If I click Yes (repair the file), I can open it and all of the data is there as expected. This does not happen with all workbooks. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with some of the formatting in the workbook but I can't figure out which one.

[Excel error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh2dN.png)

If I load the workbook and do not make changes, but save it as a separate document it opens with no errors.

Looking at the content_type.xml for the new (broken) file and the original it appears that Openpyxl is not using the same ContentType/PartName as the original document.

Code:

```
import openpyxl
import time

wb_name = 'test.xlsx'
new_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_name)
new_book.worksheets[2].insert_cols(3, 2)
output_file = "test-%s.xlsx" % time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
new_book.save(filename=output_file)
```

Original file's content_types.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
<Default Extension="bin" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings"/>
<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
<Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/sharedStrings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/drawings/drawing1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawing+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/tables/table1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/charts/chart1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/charts/style1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartstyle+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/xl/charts/colors1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.chartcolorstyle+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
<Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

Broken file's content_types.xml:

```
    <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
<Default ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" Extension="rels"/>
<Default ContentType="application/xml" Extension="xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml" PartName="/xl/sharedStrings.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml" PartName="/xl/styles.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml" PartName="/xl/theme/theme1.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml" PartName="/docProps/core.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml" PartName="/docProps/app.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table1.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table2.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table3.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table4.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet6.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table5.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table6.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet8.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table7.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet9.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table8.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet10.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table9.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet11.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table10.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet12.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table11.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table12.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet14.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table13.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet15.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table14.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet16.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table15.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet17.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table16.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet18.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table17.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet19.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table18.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet20.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.table+xml" PartName="/xl/tables/table19.xml"/>
<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml" PartName="/xl/workbook.xml"/>
</Types>
```

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with one of the tables but can't really say more without the file.

Comment: I figured out the problem but not how to fix it. The problem is that a table in the spreadsheet and when the columns are inserted the "table" info is not changed to reflect the new columns.

Comment: @Trinidad, did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: I never did figure it out.